# Python convertir un string en CamelCase a separados por guiones

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Hola estoy necesitando convertir un string en CamelCase a separado por guiones, estuve probando un poco de expresiones regulares pero no logro alguna que me separe, la idea es ingresar una cadena en CamelCase:

Entrada:

```
'HolaMundoCruel'
```

Salida:

```
'hola-mundo-cruel'
```

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) que permite subtituir cada coincidencia (en este caso una letra mayúscula en el interior de la cadena) por otra cadena dada (en este caso '-'). Para eliminar las mayúsculas puedes usar el método `lower` de la clase `str`:

```
import re

pattP = re.compile(r'(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)')
pattF = re.compile('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])')

def camel_a_guiones(cadena):
    return pattF.sub(r'\1-\2', pattP.sub(r'\1-\2', cadena)).lower()

print(camel_a_guiones('HolaMundoCruel'))
```

Otra alternativa usando `re.finditer` para separar las palabras (esto es válido también si quisieramos obtener una lista de las palabras contenidas en el camel). Teniendo esto basta volver a unirlas usando el método `join()` de `str`:

```
import re

patt = re.compile(r'.+?(?:(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|$)')
def camel_a_guiones(cadena):
    return '-'.join(m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(patt, cadena)).lower()

print(camel_a_guiones('HolaMundoCruel'))
```

Salida de ambos:

> hola-mundo-cruel

Answer (score 6):

Busquemos coincidir con el inicio de cada palabra. Hay 2 tipos de palabras en [Notación Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase):

1. Palabras iniciadas en mayúsculas, seguidas de al menos una minúscula

   ```python
   r"[A-Z][a-z]"
   ```

   En este caso, sólo nos interesa verificar que esté seguida por 1 minúscula (es lo único relevante para anteponer un guión y llevar a minúscula).

   Aunque también podría haber dígitos entre la ambas letras, y lo agregamos:

   ```python
   r"[A-Z]\d*[a-z]"
   ```

2. Siglas (mayúsculas consecutivas).

   ```python
   r"[A-Z][A-Z\d]*(?=[A-Z]|$)"
   ```

   Coincide con 1 mayúscula, seguida de más mayúsculas o dígitos `[A-Z][A-Z\d]*`.

   Pero además, que esté seguida por otra mayúscula más o el fin del texto `(?=[A-Z]|$)`.
   De esa forma, evitamos que consuma la siguiente palabra. Por ejemplo,

   - Que coincida con `HTML` en `HTMLFormateado`.
   - Pero también con `HTML` en `FormatoHTML`.

**Uniendo las dos expresiones anteriores en una, nos queda:**

```python
r"[A-Z](?:[A-Z\d]*(?=[A-Z]|$)|\d*[a-z])"
```

Esta expresión ya coincide con todos los casos. Si reemplazamos por [`r"-\g<0>"`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) (un guión seguido del texto que coincidió), tenemos:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"[A-Z](?:[A-Z\d]*(?=[A-Z]|$)|\d*[a-z])", r"-\g", "FormatoHTMLConCSS")
'-Formato-HTML-Con-CSS'
```

**No insertar guiones al inicio del texto**

Para evitar que inserte guiones al principio, vamos a pasar una función como argumento para comprobar, en cada reemplazo, si [`match.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) es `0`. Si es la primera palabra (comienza en la posición 0), no usamos un guión, de lo contrario antecedemos un guión.

Dentro de la función, usamos [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) para llevar a minúsculas.

```python
import re

patron = r"[A-Z]\d*(?:[A-Z\d]*(?=[A-Z]|$)|[a-z])"
pascal = re.compile(patron)

def pascal_kebab(cadena):
    def insertar_separador(match):
        return ("-" if match.start() else "") + match.group().lower()

    return pascal.sub(insertar_separador, cadena)
```

---

### Código final

Convierte de PascalCase a kebab-case.
Utilizamos exactamente la misma lógica que en el último código, con un lambda.

- Al utilizar un solo regex, y no depender de lookbehinds, esta función tiene un [**mejor rendimiento**](http://ideone.com/oiqjew) (30% a 100% más rápido) que las funciones utilizadas habitualmente.

```python
import re

pascal = re.compile(r"[A-Z]\d*(?:[A-Z\d]*(?=[A-Z]|$)|[a-z])")

def pascal_kebab(cadena):
    return pascal.sub(lambda m: ("-" if m.start() else "") + m.group().lower(), cadena)
```

Pruebas:

```python
pruebas = ['VerHTMLDePag', 'Ver2HTMLDePag', 'Ver2HTMLPag2Info', 'HTMLFomatoPag',
           'HTMLConXML',   'HTML5FomatoPag','HTML5ConXML',      'HTML5ConCSS3',
           'HTML',         'VerQ',          'A2BFormato',       'Formato',
           'SFormato'
          ]

for prueba in pruebas:
    print("%-16s => %s" % (prueba, pascal_kebab(prueba)))
```

Resultado:

> ```
> VerHTMLDePag     => ver-html-de-pag
> Ver2HTMLDePag    => ver2-html-de-pag
> Ver2HTMLPag2Info => ver2-html-pag2-info
> HTMLFomatoPag    => html-fomato-pag
> HTMLConXML       => html-con-xml
> HTML5FomatoPag   => html5-fomato-pag
> HTML5ConXML      => html5-con-xml
> HTML5ConCSS3     => html5-con-css3
> HTML             => html
> VerQ             => ver-q
> A2BFormato       => a2b-formato
> Formato          => formato
> SFormato         => s-formato
> ```

Demo:

http://ideone.com/Xd9mUw